# Erro na validação da assinatura no verificador do iti utilizando o demoseller para assinar o documento

Tags: demoiselle, assinatura-digital, demoiselle-certificate

Estou assinando documentos no formato CADES e utilizando a biblioteca do Demosello na versão 3.2.10  "**org.demoiselle.signer**","**org.demoiselle.signer**", e "**org.demoiselle.signer**" o ato de assinar e verificar dentro na minha aplicação esta funcionado normalmente. Para reforma os teste manuais, faço as verificações nas seguintes plataformas:

```
1.bryclound verificação
2.certisign
3.Assinador da SERPRO
4.E em uma plataforma da Europa (https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo)
```

Todos validam a assinatura como sendo correta. Porém o meu objetivo é validar no:

https://verificador.iti.gov.br/verificador.xhtml

Ele informa que houve um erro ao gerar relatório, somente isso. Alguém já enfrentou esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade aconteceu uma coisa muito esquisita. Reiniciei o computador e criei um novo projeto, e tudo funcionou normalmente. Agora tudo não faz mais sentido.

Talvez esse (https://verificador.iti.gov.br/verificador.xhtml) esteja com alguns problemas.

Comment: As vezes pode ser problema de acesso as LCR, que pode ser intermitente. Mas também não descarta alguma instabilidade do sistema. sei que estão para lançar uma nova versão do serviço em breve.